# Как трансформировать фон блока при наведении на элемент меню

Tags: html, css, menu, background, hover

Необходимо сделать такой ховер-эффект

[image: так.]

Подскажите, чем именно необходимо воспользоваться, что бы при наведении менялся фон, имел такой наклон?
И еще мне очень важно знать, как правильно в такой ситуации (используя такой ховер) распологать элементы меню:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
```

или для каждого пункта меню прописывать свои маргины?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь `transform: skew`

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #87b301;
}
li {
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  transition: .2s;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  transform: skew(15deg);
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
li:hover {
  background-color: #ebb713;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">О компании</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Справочник</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Продукция</a></li>
</ul>
```